# Very slow sites on plesk 12 , nginx having 7000+ connections

Tags: apache, nginx, plesk

'm using plesk 12 on dedicated i5 2300 16 gb ram server.

Apache is main web server and nginx is set as reverse proxy. If i stop nginx site runs ok but after a while they take too long to open but connections goes down from 7000+ to few 100.

If i start nginx site runs ok but after a while they take too long to open and connections goes up from 100 to 7000+.